# .net 5 dynamically loading a DLL and all dependencies

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, mef, .net-5, system.reflection

I have a .Net 5 worker service that dynamically loads a DLL at runtime and calls a method to setup additional dependency injection.

```
Activator.CreateInstance(helperClass) as IDependencyInjectionHelper
helper.SetupInjection(hostContext, services);
```

This works fine for simple implementations, but now I have library that needs EntityFramework.  My worker service does not have a refence to entity framework and throws this error at runtime:

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=5.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

If I add EntityFrameworkCore to my worker service everything works, but the reason for loading libraries dynamically is that I don't know everything that is needed in the future.

I also tried to implement this by following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support).  When the code calls assembly.GetTypes(), it throws an exception:

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or
> more of the requested types. Method 'SetupInjection' in type
> 'TestDatabaseConsumer.InjectionHelper' from assembly
> 'TestDatabaseConsumer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' **does not have an implementation**.'

The exception says my class does not implement my interface, but it does.
I've also tried an MEF but it throws the same exception as above.

How can I load these dependent libraries at runtime?

Comment: When you service is running, the current/execution directory is somewhere else than where the assembly is located. If i recall correctly, there is a property where you can set additional paths when loading dynamically.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support#:~:text=The%20PluginLoadContext%20type%20derives%20from%20AssemblyLoadContext.%20The%20AssemblyLoadContext,groups%20to%20ensure%20that%20assembly%20versions%20don%27t%20conflict.

Comment: I followed that tutorial.  When it didn't work, I changed the approach and get a similar error.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Does your assembly that contains IDependencyInjectionHelper interface is loaded in the same AssemblyLoadContext where helperClass-containing assembly is loaded? Other words, maybe both interface and implementation are loaded using different instances of AssemblyLoadContext?